# Button not overriding parent's IsEnabled

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls, isenabled

I have a custom control that displays a tryAgain button when the control is disabled.

This nesting is causing the button to become disabled, even if I explicitly enable the `Button` in xaml or with a trigger.  Is there a way to override a parent control's `IsEnabled`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The button can't be a child of the whatever parent is disabled.  Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <CustomControl IsEnabled="False">
    </CustomControl>
    <Button Content="TryAgain"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I am now using a different property to express the concept of my custom control like "IsAvailable" to effect the template and expose the button.